# Find and replace table data with another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, inner-join

In my MySQL database, I have two tables, `item` and `users`. In the item table I have two columns called `created_by` and `created_by_alias`. The created by alias column is fully populated with names but the `created_by` column is empty. The next table I have is the `users` table. This has the `id` and `name` columns inside of it.

I would like to know whether it is possible to use MySQL to match the `created_by_alias` in the item table with the `name` column in the `users` table, then take the id of the user and put it into the `created_by` column.

I was thinking some sort of `JOIN` function. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Joins are the right path - Presuming you can join the two tables by a unique id, just perform an update. You can use `set items.created_by_alias = users.name` and it will update to whatever name value matches according to the join. (Disclaimer: I'm experienced with SQL server, not so much MySQL)

Comment: @tjennings Great, I'll back up the database and try this, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are indeed in the right direction  - MySQL has an `update join` syntax:

```sql
UPDATE items
JOIN   users ON users.name = items.created_by_alias
SET    created_by = items.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
UPDATE items
SET created_by = (SELECT u.id 
                  FROM users u
                  WHERE u.name = items.created_by_alias)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE item i 
INNER JOIN users u ON i.created_by_alias = u.name
SET i.created_by = u.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work in MySQL

```
UPDATE item 
       INNER JOIN users 
               ON item.created_by_alias = users.name 
SET    item.created_by = users.id
```

Of course you should also check that all users names are unique...